# refreshToken() not working in google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

Am using PHP client library provided by Google. Also using web applications in Google API console. When i try to refresh my token its return "Google_AuthException' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"   " .Please Help me how refresh my token

This in My Sample code

```
ini_set("memory_limit", -1);
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google+ PHP Starter Application");
$client->setClientId('XXXXXXXXXXX');
$client->setClientSecret('XXXXXXXXXX');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost:1134/Google%20APIs/index.php');
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
$SCOPES = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
$client->setScopes($SCOPES);
$drive = new Google_DriveService($client);
$token ='{"access_token":"XXXXXXXX","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","refresh_token":"XXX","created":1396703189}';
$client->setAccessToken($token);
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken("1\/ccccccxxxxx");
}
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $user = $client->about;
    $ret = retrieveAllFiles($drive);
    //var_dump($ret);
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
    $result = array();
    $pageToken = NULL;

    do {
        try {
            $parameters = array();
            if ($pageToken) {
                $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            }
            $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

            $result = array_merge($result, $files['items']);
            $pageToken = $files['nextPageToken'];
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
            $pageToken = NULL;
        }
    } while ($pageToken);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: why is the token value inline in the code? what exactly are you passing to `$client->refreshToken()`? you should be saving the token returned by `$client->getAccessToken()` somewhere and loading it to get the refresh token

Comment: paste the http request and response into your question

Comment: @vinicius this code for testing so that only I am hardcode the value . I am passinig refresh_token value that was returned from Google

Comment: @pinoyyid my http response from Google is http response code is 400 . Response body return invalid_grant please help to debug this . I am really struggled in this point

Comment: I said paste the **http request** and response

Comment: @pinoyyid I can not able to type the entire code here .So use the following link to refer the code and help me . i am really struggle in this point http://justpaste.it/f00u

Comment: for the last time... we need to see the **http request**

Comment: Heads up your using the old Client lib. You might want to try with the new one https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: @DalamTo thank you so much . Its working fine now . In earlier i did not use json decode that is the major problem i hope. ( client lib returns refresh_ token with slash )